# Comparing files for similarities

Tags: linux, comparison, diff

Is there a standard Linux tool that looks for similarities between two files? The `diff` tool works best comparing files that are mostly the same, and outputs where they differ. I'm looking for a tool to compare files that are mostly different, and output their similarities.

Comment: Some good answers at [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/746458/how-to-show-lines-in-common-reverse-diff)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`comm -12 file1 file2` will print the lines that exist in both files; I think it only works for sorted files, though.

Comment: The files won't be sorted, but I think this is going to be my best option.

Answer (score 1):

You mught try using `vimdiff` or `gvimdiff`. However, they too find differences raather than similarities. 
I doubt an application for what you suggested exists.

Comment: Yeah, I use `vimdiff` a lot. These files are too different for that to be useful though.